# how I can control text of selected item in list item in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am a beginner in PL/SQL and Oracle Forms .

I am working in an Oracle form. Created a push button and updated it to item type: list item. I want to choose between items when I click on it. I should redirect with if according to the item  chose. How can I do that?
NOTE: I'am using `forms 6i` ,

> **item_type**  : *list item*
>
> **list style** : *popup list*
>
> **elements in list** : ***S_SATIS**(value : **item24**)* - ***S_MARKA**(value : **item25**)*
>
> **trigger** : *when-list-changed*

This is how I got list item name and values:

```sql
l_count := GET_LIST_ELEMENT_COUNT('list_item');
FOR i in 1..l_count LOOP
   IF GET_LIST_ELEMENT_VALUE('list-item',i) = :list_item THEN
      l_text := GET_LIST_ELEMENT_LABEL('list_item',i);
      l_value := Name_In('list_item');
```

I want to redirect according to the item  selected with if. This is the method I think is correct. But it is not working correctly. I used message to see if it goes inside the if . but it didn't print the message. How can I fix?

```sql
ELSIF l_value = '<list item value name>' THEN
  message(l_value);
  GO_BLOCK('<block_name>');
  EXECUTE_QUERY
```

Comment: Hi @wetbutterfly , I asked you to "Describe what have you done (on your form) to get this error". So, you run some form and then you click something ? Right ? Under what trigger have you wrote that code ? Every item on your form has some triggers, this is important. Details... details. You can return the photo you had at the first version of the picture and the whole code. What I wanted to suggest is to leave only one if then statement that produces the error and start from there. It is important that people know if you declared all the variables and how...

Comment: you're right,I did what you said. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ELSIF l_text = '<list item name>' THEN
  message(l_text );
  GO_BLOCK('<block_name>');
  EXECUTE_QUERY
```

this way the problem is solved